# MySQL Set AutoIncrement "Ad Hoc"

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Is there a way to set mysql's auto_increment to a certain integer in an "ad hoc" way - for example, N  of the latest rows have been deleted in a table, so the primary key/auto_increment is N off from the actual # of rows? Is there a way to set the auto_increment to the right number, or to manually set it?

This seems common, so I believe it has been asked already, but I've not been able to find a solution, other than that this isn't possible or you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 3):

ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;